# Finding the sum of time for overlapping values

Tags: php, mysql, math

I have been struggling with this question for a couple of days. I have one machine which can have errors. In a database I have the starting and ending time (in unix time) when the error appeared, and the type of error (number from 5-12). The problem I'm having is that multiple errors can occur at the same time (and overlap).

My table looks like this:

```
   id| type | from       | to
    1| 6    | 1417179933 | 1417180006
    2| 6    | 1417180035 | 1417180065
    3| 9    | 1417180304 | 1417180409
    4| 6    | 1417180662 | 1417184364
    5| 8    | 1417180662 | 1417186832
    6| 9    | 1417180662 | 1417184364
    7| 12   | 1417180662 | 1417184364
    8| 6    | 1417184364 | 1417186832
    9| 9    | 1417184364 | 1417188054
```

I need to find the total duration of errors for this machine. I can't sum all differences from the above table since it's possible that two or more errors appeared in the same time interval. Records are sorted in ascending order.

My guess was to compare each record (start and finishing time) with previous and then find the difference in seconds. However, this table can grow over time and it is a problem to search through it.

Is there a clever way in PHP or MySQL to find total time where the machine didn't work, possibly in minutes?

Comment: `SELECT SUM(to - from) / 60 AS allTime FROM table`? Or if the 2 errors overlapping, then you just want to calculate the rest?

Comment: well, maybe in this example there are two errors overlapping (after checking, no there's more) but in real table it can be n overlapping. So only differences which aren't overlap should be calculated. Am I right?

Comment: Oh, i see. Then I missunderstood your question.

Comment: 4 upvotes? Some questions just capture the zeitgeist, don't they? ;-)

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Comment: desired result is just time in minutes for how long machine didn't work. I must check all answers tomorrow and let you know. Thank you for the effort!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a general approach to summing intervals taking into account potential overlaps, supposing intervals are sorted on their lower value.

### 2 intervals case

When adding two intervals `[a,b]` and `[c,d]`, thus `(d-c) + (b-a)` you count their overlap twice.

- **If the overlap is non-zero,** then its value is `min(b,d) - max(a,c)`. Since you sorted items on the start of the interval, then you know that `max(a,c) == c`.
- **If the overlap is 0**, `a <= b <= c <= d` so `min(b,d) == b`, `max(a,c) == c`, and `min(b,d) - max(a,c) == b - c <= 0`. You awlays want to remove `0` however.

Thus a general formula is `d-c + b-a - max(0,min(b,d)-c)`

### Generalizing to more intervals

To generalize to more intervals than two, just consider that when you add a new interval `[c,d]` to any number of previous intervals, you add `(d-c)` and the overlap that is counted twice is between `[c,d]` and the union of all previous intervals.

Since you sort intervals on their start values, you only need to consider the last continuous interval of this union, thus for you the last continuous period of downtime.

If `[a,b]` is your previous last continuous interval and you've just added `[c,d]`:

- **If `[a,b]` and `[c,d]` overlap**, your last continuous interval becomes `[a, max(b,d)]` because this is the union of `[a,b]` and `[c,d]`
- **If `[a,b]` and `[c,d]` do not overlap**, your last continuous interval becomes `[c, d]` (NB: we have `max(b,d) == b`)

Since `a < c` because of sorted intervals, the **intervals overlap iff `c < b`**

### In code

That is probably easier to implement in php than mysql. In pseudo code, assuming each row returns a (start,end) error interval, and `[a,b]` is your last known continuous interval:

```
(a,b) = get_first_row();
downtime = b-a;
while( (c,d) = get_next_row() )
{
     downtime += d-c - max(0, min(d,b)-c);
     a = c < b ? a : c;
     b = max(b,d);
}
```

You can see this code run successfully here : https://3v4l.org/Q2phs

Comment: Is this an answer? I'm not convinced.

Comment: @Strawberry is it not ? It'd be easy to do in PHP, which is what's asked. Less messy that MySQL for that I'm sure. I might not writing copy/paste code, but apart from that, what's bothering you ?

Comment: @Strawberry I added a link to a 3v4l so you can see it works :) http://3v4l.org/GOCFh

Comment: OK, now I'm convinced ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Non-database approach. Probably, it might be modified for databases.

```
  Start   Finish
  10      13
  12      15
  16      18
```

Join both start times and finish times together in one sorted list or array with start flag.

```
  Time           IsStart
10              Yes
12              Yes
13              No
15              No
16              Yes
....
```

Make ActiveCounter = 0, walk through the list.
Increment ActiveCounter if IsStart, decrement otherwise
When ActiveCounter becomes > 0, error interval begins,
when ActiveCounter becomes = 0, error interval ends.

```
Time    ActCnt
10      1       //error state begins
12      2       //it continues
13      1       //still continues
15      0       //the end!  T = 15-10 = 5
16      1       //new error state begins
```

Answer (score 1):

Stealing an idea from Peterm [Calculate total time excluding overlapped time & breaks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741031/calculate-total-time-excluding-overlapped-time-breaks-in-mysql/26741489#26741489)

```
 SELECT SUM(seconds) total
   FROM
 (
   SELECT MAX(to_date) - MIN(from_date) seconds
     FROM
   (
     SELECT from_date, to_date,
            @g := IF(@e BETWEEN from_date AND to_date OR to_date <= @e, @g, @g + 1) g,
            @e := to_date
       FROM my_table CROSS JOIN 
     (
       SELECT @g := 0, @e := NULL
     ) i
      ORDER BY from_date, to_date
   ) q
    GROUP BY g
 ) q;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's MBO's answer turned into php code.

```
function sumDateTimeDurations(array $datePairs){
        $list = [];
        $numlength = strlen((string)(count($datePairs)*2)); 
        $keyCtr = pow(10 ,$numlength);//Keep the keys unique and sortable
        foreach($datePairs as $pair){
            $list[$pair[0]->getTimestamp() . ($keyCtr++)] = [$pair[0]->getTimestamp(),true]; //true = start
            $list[$pair[1]->getTimestamp() . ($keyCtr++)] = [$pair[1]->getTimestamp(),false]; //false = end
        }
        ksort($list);
        $activeCounter = 0;
        $totalSeconds = 0;
        $lastStart = null;
        foreach($list as $ele){
            $ele[1]?$activeCounter++:$activeCounter--;
            if ($ele[1] && $activeCounter == 1){
                $lastStart = $ele[0];

            }
            if (!$ele[1] && $activeCounter == 0){
                $totalSeconds += ($ele[0]) - $lastStart;
            }
        }
        return $totalSeconds;
    }
```

Example:

```
$datePairs[] = [new DateTime("2022-07-18 11:31:22.141183", new DateTimeZone("UTC")),new DateTime("2022-07-18 11:32:22.141183", new DateTimeZone("UTC"))];
$datePairs[] = [new DateTime("2022-07-18 11:31:52.141183", new DateTimeZone("UTC")),new DateTime("2022-07-18 11:32:23.141183", new DateTimeZone("UTC"))];
$seconds = sumDateTimeDurations($datePairs);
```